# Need assistance wiht jquery draggable z-index issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, z-index, draggable

I've got the code below working well, so that when a block is dragged, it's on top of the other blocks.  But, I'm not sure what to add so that when the user drops the box, the z-index is updated and the box remains on top.  Right now when the box is dropped it goes under other boxes, retaining its original z-index. I did see this (// Setter
$( ".selector" ).draggable( "option", "zIndex", 100 );) in the API documentation, just not sure how it should be integrated into my working code below. Thanks for any ideas!

```
$(function(){
    var positions = JSON.parse(localStorage.positions || "{}");
    $(function () {
        var d = $("[id=draggable]").attr("id", function (i) {
            return "draggable_" + i
        })
        $.each(positions, function (id, pos) {
            $("#" + id).css(pos);
        })

        d.draggable({
            containment: "#containment-wrapper",
            zIndex: 100,
            scroll: false,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                positions[this.id] = ui.position
                localStorage.positions = JSON.stringify(positions)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least two options:

- Keep track of the maximum set index and whenever an element is moved, set it's index to maximum + 1, So it will always be on top when dropped.

  ```
  var maxZIndex = 1; // or something else
  d.draggable({
      // ...
      start: function (event, ui) {
          maxZIndex++;
          ui.helper.zIndex(maxZIndex);
          $(event.target).zIndex(maxZIndex);
      }
      //...
  });
  ```
- If you are not just dragging your element somewhere, but dropping it on another element, you can use `droppable` to get the drop event and set the z-index to the z-index of the droppable element + 1.

  ```
  yourDroppables.droppable({
      // ...
      drop: function(event, ui) {
          var zIndex = $(event.target).zIndex()
          ui.draggable.zIndex(zIndex + 1);
      }
      // ...
  });
  ```

Comment: Would you mind showing how the code you provided should be worked into what I have above?  I tried it myself, but was getting syntax errors and couldn't get it working.

Comment: The first version is pretty close to what you are asking for. Maybe you can post your code in a https://jsfiddle.net/ and I can help you fix the syntax errors.

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer. This means others won't have to look at it again because it's solved and I earn some reputation.

Comment: Happy to, just not sure how to :)... new to this site.  Tried to click the up arrow but said I can't yet do that...?

Comment: Click the tick below the arrows ;-)